# Flutter Create dynamic widget from dynamic json response

Tags: arrays, json, flutter, api, arraylist

```
 companyList = data['fields'][0]['choices'];
    if (companyList.length != 0) {
      int val;
      for (val = 0; val < companyList.length; val++) {
        final controller = TextEditingController();
        final field = xTextfield(
          txtlabel: "Values",
          iconfield: bookmarksIcon,
        );

        setState(() {
          _controllers.add(controller);
          _fields.add(field);
        });
      }
    }
```

But this works only if json response is same when it changes and Array object is differnet i got error here is my json that will be different everytime e.g

"inputtype": "dropdown", will make a dropdown widget and all data will be put into it and so on

> `{ "fields": [ { "id": 31, "name": "make", "isrequired": "required", "valuetype": "text", "priority": 1, "inputtype": "dropdown", "max_min": [], "rangeable": "false", "choices": [ { "id": 46, "name": "Samsung", "categoryextrafield_id": 31, "created_at": "2021-12-29T01:30:47.000000Z", "updated_at": "2021-12-29T01:30:47.000000Z", "priority": 10 }, { "id": 47, "name": "Dell", "categoryextrafield_id": 31, "created_at": "2021-12-29T01:30:52.000000Z", "updated_at": "2021-12-29T01:30:52.000000Z", "priority": 20 }, { "id": 48, "name": "IBM", "categoryextrafield_id": 31, "created_at": "2021-12-29T01:31:09.000000Z", "updated_at": "2021-12-29T01:31:09.000000Z", "priority": 30 }, { "id": 49, "name": "Acer", "categoryextrafield_id": 31, "created_at": "2021-12-29T01:31:24.000000Z", "updated_at": "2021-12-29T01:31:24.000000Z", "priority": 40 } ], "available": [] }, { "id": 32, "name": "model", "isrequired": "required", "valuetype": "text", "priority": 2, "inputtype": "textfield", "max_min": [], "rangeable": "false", "choices": [], "available": [ { "model": "a51" }, { "model": "y9s" }, { "model": "a31" }, { "model": "yS10" }, { "model": "Y10S" }, { "model": "A551" }, { "model": "node8" }, { "model": "s9" }, { "model": null }, { "model": "2021" }, { "model": "2020" }, { "model": "2010" }, { "model": "Civic" }, { "model": "2019" }, { "model": "Daewooy9" }, { "model": "corei5" }, { "model": "corei9" }, { "model": "corei3" }, { "model": "corei11" } ] }, { "id": 29, "name": "features", "isrequired": "required", "valuetype": "text", "priority": 3, "inputtype": "checkbox", "max_min": [], "rangeable": "false", "choices": [ { "id": 41, "name": "Bluetooth", "categoryextrafield_id": 29, "created_at": "2021-12-29T01:19:00.000000Z", "updated_at": "2021-12-29T01:19:00.000000Z", "priority": 1 }, { "id": 42, "name": "Fingerprint", "categoryextrafield_id": 29, "created_at": "2021-12-29T01:19:10.000000Z", "updated_at": "2021-12-29T01:19:10.000000Z", "priority": 10 }, { "id": 43, "name": "LedDisplay", "categoryextrafield_id": 29, "created_at": "2021-12-29T01:19:35.000000Z", "updated_at": "2021-12-29T01:19:35.000000Z", "priority": 15 } ], "available": [] }, { "id": 30, "name": "condition", "isrequired": "required", "valuetype": "text", "priority": 4, "inputtype": "radiobutton", "max_min": [], "rangeable": "false", "choices": [ { "id": 44, "name": "Used", "categoryextrafield_id": 30, "created_at": "2021-12-29T01:20:31.000000Z", "updated_at": "2021-12-29T01:20:31.000000Z", "priority": 10 }, { "id": 45, "name": "New", "categoryextrafield_id": 30, "created_at": "2021-12-29T01:20:38.000000Z", "updated_at": "2021-12-29T01:20:38.000000Z", "priority": 20 } ], "available": [] } ] }`

Comment: can you share changes json error snapsort

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [Dynamic Widget](https://pub.dev/packages/dynamic_widget) package.

Just pass the widget as JSON data from the server and use a `FutureBuilder` to build it when your data arrives.

You will also need to change your JSON data accordingly.